# How to check if a field is null on payload from request body in Mulesoft?

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I have 2 scenarios.

request body:

```
 {
    "id"="",
    "name"="Jane"
 }
```

Expected result:

"Success"

request body:

```
 {
    "id"="323",
    "name"="Jane"
 }
```

Expected result:
"id field should be emptied."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this following dataweave will help you achieve what you are looking for

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    output: 'Success' when 
    payload.id == null or payload.id == "" 
    otherwise 'id field should be emptied.'
}
```

[image]

[image]